# Create object automatically for each instance user gives values in java

Tags: java, object

I want to create object and store that in non static variables
is it possible to create it automatically

```
    Scanner scn= new Scanner(System.in);
    Values v1=new Values();
    System.out.println("Enter the l and b of rectangle : ");
    
    int area=0,perimeter=0;
    
    scan();
    v1.intilaise(len, bre);
    v1.display();
    area =v1.area();
    perimeter=v1.perimeter();
    System.out.println("Area of Rectangle :"+area);
    System.out.println("Perimeter of Rectangle : "+perimeter);
    scan();
    Values v2=new Values();
    v2.intilaise(len,bre);
    v2.display();
    System.out.println("Area of rectangle : "+(v2.area()));
    System.out.println("Perimeter of Rectangle : "+(v2.perimeter()));
    
    int i=3;
    do {
        while(true)
        {
            i++;
            Values v[I)= new Values();//where I value should change like 3 4 5 ...values v3 v4 v5....new object needs to be created each time user gives 'Y'

        }
        
        System.out.print("Enter Y if you want to continue");
        char ans=scn.next().charAt(0);
        } while (ans=='Y'||ans=='y');
```

//For each instance user gives 'Y' I want to create another object and store the user input
please help

Comment: Inside the while, if ans is equal to Y, you can generate a new Object and store it in a list. I am not sure if I understood your question, can you review it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to store but a couple examples might be:

```
List<Dimension> rectDimensions = new ArrayList<>();
rectDimensions.add(new Dimension(yourWidth, yourHeight));
```

or perhaps:

```
List<Values> vals = new ArrayList<>();
vals.add(v1));
vals.add(v2));
```

or what you might be actually looking for is something like:

```
List<Values> vals = new ArrayList<>();
vals.add(new Values());
```